# how to call dialog fragment with listview and search filter from a fragment and save selected item value in parent fragment as string?

Tags: java, android

```
public class fragment_oneway_flight extends Fragment {


    private Spinner spinner1 ;
    Context thiscontext;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
    int countadult=  1;
    int countchild=  0;
    int countinfant= 0;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog,pDialog1;

    TextView quantity_adult_textview, quantity_child_textview, quantity_infant_textview, textview_city_slct_from_oneway, textview_city_slct_to_oneway;

    private ImageButton increment_adult_Button, decrement_adult_Button, increment_child_Button, decrement_child_Button, increment_infant_Button, decrement_infant_Button;

    private Button prcdtoonwyrslt;

    public fragment_oneway_flight() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        thiscontext = container.getContext();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_oneway_flight, container, false);

        LinearLayout select_dep_date = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_from_select_oneway);
        select_dep_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

                // Show the date picker dialog fragment
                dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

            }

        });

        LinearLayout city_slct_from_oneway = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.city_slct_from_oneway);
        city_slct_from_oneway.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogBoxFragment DialogBoxFragment = new DialogBoxFragment ();
                DialogBoxFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog");

            }

        });

        LinearLayout city_slct_to_oneway = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.city_slct_to_oneway);
        city_slct_to_oneway.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogBoxFragment2 DialogBoxFragment2 = new DialogBoxFragment2 ();
                DialogBoxFragment2.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog2");

            }

        });

        prcdtoonwyrslt = (Button) rootView.findViewById( R.id.prcdtoonwyrslt );
        prcdtoonwyrslt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), activity_flight_result_oneway.class);

                pDialog1 = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog1.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                pDialog1.setCancelable(false);

                String countadult = quantity_adult_textview.getText().toString();

                String countchild = quantity_child_textview.getText().toString();

                String countinfant = quantity_infant_textview.getText().toString();

                String selectedfromcity = textview_city_slct_from_oneway.getText().toString();

                String selectedtocity = textview_city_slct_to_oneway.getText().toString();

                intent.putExtra("adultsnos", countadult);

                intent.putExtra("childsnos", countchild);

                intent.putExtra("infantsnos", countinfant);

                intent.putExtra("fromcity", selectedfromcity);

                intent.putExtra("tocity", selectedtocity);



                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        // button function start
        increment_adult_Button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById( R.id.increment_adult_Button );
        decrement_adult_Button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById( R.id.decrement_adult_Button );
        increment_child_Button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById( R.id.increment_child_Button );
        decrement_child_Button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById( R.id.decrement_child_Button );
        increment_infant_Button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById( R.id.increment_infant_Button );
        decrement_infant_Button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById( R.id.decrement_infant_Button );
        quantity_adult_textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_adult_textview);
        quantity_child_textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_child_textview);
        quantity_infant_textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_infant_textview);

        increment_adult_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countadult++;
                if(countadult>7){
                    countadult=7;
                }
                display(countadult);

            }
        });

        decrement_adult_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countadult--;
                if(countadult<1){
                    countadult=1;
                }
                display(countadult);
            }
        });


        increment_child_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countchild++;
                if(countchild>5){
                    countchild=5;
                }

                display(countchild);
            }
        });


        decrement_child_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countchild--;
                if(countchild<0){
                    countchild=0;
                }
                display(countchild);
            }
        });


        increment_infant_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countinfant++;
                if(countinfant>5){
                    countinfant=5;
                }
                display(countinfant);
            }
        });


        decrement_infant_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countinfant--;
                if(countinfant<0){
                    countinfant=0;
                }
                display(countinfant);
            }
        });


        // button function end


        setSpinnerContent( rootView );

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> id, View rootView, int pos, long arg3) {

                if (pos == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Select Class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else if (pos == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have selected Economy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else if (pos == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have selected Premium Economy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else if (pos == 3) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have selected Business", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }else if (pos == 4) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have selected First Class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });


        return rootView;


    }


    private void setSpinnerContent( View rootView ) {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById( R.id.spinner_flight );
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.flight_class_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter( adapter );
    }



    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            /*
                Initialize a new DatePickerDialog

                DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack,
                    int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
             */

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DateDialog,this,year,month,day);
            return  dpd;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
            // Do something with the chosen date
            TextView dep_date_flight = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_dep_date);

            // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
            cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
            Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();

            // Format the date using style and locale
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
            String formattedDate = df.format(chosenDate);

            // Display the chosen date to app interface
            dep_date_flight.setText(formattedDate);

        }
    }


    private void display(int number) {
        quantity_adult_textview.setText(String.valueOf(countadult));
        quantity_child_textview.setText(String.valueOf(countchild));
        quantity_infant_textview.setText(String.valueOf(countinfant));
    }

    public static class DialogBoxFragment extends DialogFragment {

        //declaring variables
        private ListView listviewforresults;
        //Adapter for listview
        ArrayAdapter<String> list1adapter;
        //Edittext for search
        EditText searchdata;
        //ArrayList for listview
        ArrayList<String>  data=new ArrayList<String>();




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View rootView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city_select_flight, container, false);
            prepareDummyData();

            listviewforresults=(ListView)rootView1.findViewById(R.id.showdata);
            searchdata=(EditText)rootView1.findViewById(R.id.searchdata);




            //set data to Adapter
            list1adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), country_list,R.id.results,data);
            listviewforresults.setAdapter(list1adapter);
            //search data when text changes in edittext
            searchdata.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    list1adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });

            listviewforresults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    String selectedFromList = (String) listviewforresults.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    TextView textview_city_slct_from_oneway = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textview_city_slct_from_oneway);
                    textview_city_slct_from_oneway.setText(selectedFromList);
                    getDialog().dismiss();

                }
            });



            getDialog().setTitle("dialog");
            return rootView1;
        }

        public void prepareDummyData()
        {
            data.add("Chennai");
            data.add("Mumbai");
            data.add("Bangalore");
            data.add("Madurai");
            data.add("Coimbatore");
            data.add("Newdelhi");
        }

    }

    public static class DialogBoxFragment2 extends DialogFragment {

        //declaring variables
        private ListView listviewforresults2;
        //Adapter for listview
        ArrayAdapter<String> list2adapter;
        //Edittext for search
        EditText searchdata;
        //ArrayList for listview
        ArrayList<String>  data=new ArrayList<String>();


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city_select_flight2, container, false);
            prepareDummyData2();

            listviewforresults2=(ListView)rootView2.findViewById(R.id.showdata);
            searchdata=(EditText)rootView2.findViewById(R.id.searchdata);


            //set data to Adapter
            list2adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), country_list,R.id.results,data);
            listviewforresults2.setAdapter(list2adapter);
            //search data when text changes in edittext
            searchdata.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    list2adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });

            listviewforresults2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    String selectedFromList2 = (String) listviewforresults2.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    TextView textview_city_slct_to_oneway = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textview_city_slct_to_oneway);
                    textview_city_slct_to_oneway.setText(selectedFromList2);
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            });

            getDialog().setTitle("dialog2");
            return rootView2;
        }

        public void prepareDummyData2() {
            data.add("Chennai");
            data.add("Mumbai");
            data.add("Bangalore");
            data.add("Madurai");
            data.add("Coimbatore");
            data.add("Newdelhi");
        }

    }

}
```

the above code is full fragment code with gialog innerclass too. im a beginner can you gys help me out of it?

and actually what i need is i have to click the from and to area in tab view fragment. after slecting it opens a dialog with search filter and listview. after clicking any list item it should diaplay in textview on parent fragment and after that i should be able wo pass the value to next fragment using put intent method.

currently im getting null value when i pass it to the next fragment.

i dont know why.

i have attached an image to get you the clear view. please check it.[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRPr7.jpg)